# Updated from 3.8 to 4.2 and all post types changed to "post"

Tags: custom-post-types, updates, post-type

My client updated his website from WordPress 3.8.x to 4.2.1 in order to make a plugin verify as working correctly. We were holding off originally to do it and some other plugins all at once so we could have a full backup first, but alas, "Update Now" was clicked and it seems the update broke our site.

My question is, **what could cause the update process to change all of the `wp_posts` table `post_type` fields to "post"?** Prior, there were 7-8 custom post types in addition to the standard `page` and `attachment` types. Now we have just over 31 thousand Posts and no other `post_type`, only a handful of which are actually supposed to be posts. I disabled all plugins, re-installed WP 4.2, but there was no effect since the change is right in the database.

We are using a customized theme built on WP's TwentyTen theme. There was a number of plugins installed at time of updating:

- advanced-custom-fields-pro
- breadcrumb-trail
- capsman
- [cta](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cta/)
- landing-pages
- leads
- per-post-scripts-and-styles
- peters-login-redirect
- regenerate-thumbnails
- [soliloquy-lite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/soliloquy-lite/)
- [the-events-calendar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/) * This one is what caused us to update, if that's relevant
- user-role-editor
- woocommerce
- wordpress-access-control
- wp-mailto-links

Any ideas, maybe we can prevent someone else from having the same issue.

Comment: You do have a database backup, do you? I guess, it was one of the plugins. Search in their support forums.

Comment: Nothing in the core `upgrade_{400,420,421}()` functions suggests such a modification, afaik. Maybe you could setup a demo 3.8 install again with those plugins and then the "record" the database calls (via the query hook), while you upgrade to 4.2? But that might or might not give some clues? Hope you got a backup!

Comment: Maybe you can also check the mysql logs, if available. It's also possible to turn on logging in my.conf, to monitor all queries for debugging purposes (heavy).

Comment: Ended up querying `wp_postmeta` to find unique-per-post_type keys and updating the post_type based on that. Few hours, better than manually one at a time! Needless to say, we're backing up their data twice a week now.